# Web UI Pipeline for build automation

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, gulp

I am using Node and Gulp with some modules to create a UI pipeline, but I want to know if there are some less complex solutions. My web application is a collection of html pages, of course. They all have the same header, footer, and navigation. They all have two common JS and CSS files (libraries). However, the content itself is of course different.

Are there any services to build a UI pipeline (like Gulp) that will take common HTML files and other resources as well as specific page resources (html/css/js) and create a single page app out of them? Or is using Gulp to pull and concat files the best way..

The reason I ask is because it is cumbersome to inject the CSS and JS files into the `<header></header>` tag without having tiny HTML files to also inject, that consists of nothing other than a closing`<tag>`

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I understand you right, you inject CSS and JS files and concat it after with other html files to get the closing tags?

Think you need just this plugin: [gulp-inject](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inject). Which will inject the files on right place.

Gulp is not a tool to create single page apps. It's an automatisation and build tool. To create a single page app you will need something like Angular/Ember/Aurelia/React or an other JS framework.

Comment: Thanks - inject is what I am looking for.